# how to download files in production mode in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to download files which doesn't work in production mode. my storage link is below
inside public_html->storage->source->my files

and here is the code

```
    public function getGo(Request $request, $link){
    $get = base64_decode($link);

    $file=public_path().$get;

    return response()->file($file);
}
```

but it shows an error in production mode saying
/home/myproject/lib/public/storage/source/myfile.png" does not exist

how will i get rid of this problem

Comment: Does `/home/myproject/lib/public/storage/source/myfile.png` really exist on your server?

Comment: yes the file exist. but maybe its unable to download

Comment: I hope file permissions are ok.  Also, to initiate the download, you will to have pass headers as the 2nd parameter I presume. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-responses

Comment: You have image files in `public_html/storage/source/my files`, but you are accessing `/home/myproject/lib/public/storage/source/myfile.png` ? Because `public_html` is where you will have hosted your Laravel project.

Comment: yeah vivek. i tried with the code below as well which clearly finds the path but still cant download
        $file=asset('storage/source/hey.png');

        return response()->download($file);